# How to use `--files-from` `rsync` option to download a list of files?

Tags: download, rsync

I'm using the following command to download a folder from remote using rsync:

```
sshpass -p "my_pwd" rsync -av --partial --progress  
    <usr>@<remote>:/home/remote/folder /home/local/folder/
```

Now, instead of downloading the entire file I want to download a list of files: I've seen I can do this using the `--files-from` but it's not clear how to use this option.

I've tried to create the file by specifying the files, for example:

```
/home/remote/folder/file1
/home/remote/folder/file2
```

and I've also tried to preappend the remote:

```
 <usr>@<remote>:/home/remote/folder/file1
 <usr>@<remote>:/home/remote/folder/file2
```

and launch respectively with the command

```
sshpass -p "my_pwd" rsync -av --partial --progress --recursive 
    <usr>@<remote> --files-from=files.txt /home/local/folder/
```

or

```
sshpass -p "my_pwd" rsync -av --partial --progress --recursive 
    --files-from=files.txt /home/local/folder/
```

but neither worked.

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the command, I will leave the question in case someone need instead of deleting it

```
sshpass -p "my_pwd" rsync -av --partial --progress --recursive 
    <usr>@<remote>:/home/remote/folder --files-from=files.txt /home/local/folder/
```

having the following file

```
file1
file2
```